# Prove properties about equation $-u’’+u=u^p$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, maximum-principle

Assume that $p>1,u\ge0,u\in H^1(\mathbb R),u(0)=\Vert u\Vert_{L^\infty}$, and $u$ satisfies that
$$-u’’+u=u^p$$
Prove that $u(0)>1,u$ is even and is strictly decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$
$$$$
It is easy to prove $u$ is smooth, but I didn’t figure out about the decreasing property. It seems that we can use maximum principle or something but I don’t know how to do. Are there any suggestions about this problem?

Comment: The appears to be a question which requires the method of moving planes. You may find something in the following notes helpful. https://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math581w19/581p.pdf